# Node.js / Express.js - Fail to get form data and save to db

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I tried to make a registration form and save to database (via mLab cloud db), however after submitting the form, the server fail to get the data and no response either. I am new to MEAN Stack, please advise if I make any stupid mistakes.
Many thanks in advance.

controller.js

```
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const userModel = require('../model/userModel');app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//create acc
app.post('/userSignUp', function(req, res){
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(404);

  var newUser = new userModel({
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });

  //save user to db
  newUser.save(function(err){
    if (err) throw err;

  // fetch user and test password verification
  userModel.findOne({username:req.body.username}, function(err, user){
    if (err) throw err;

    // test a matching password
    user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function(err, isMatch){
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(req.body.password, isMatch);
      res.render('/index.ejs');
    });
  });
});});
```

sign-up form

```
<!-- Sign up form -->
    <div id="signup_form" style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;">
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        <form action="userSignUp" method="get">
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                    <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
                            <label for="checkbox">remember</label>
                    </span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
            </form>
    </div>
```

userModel

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } },
password: { type: String, required: true }
```

});

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
var user = this;

// only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

// generate a salt
bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
if (err) return next(err);

// hash the password using our new salt
bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
    user.password = hash;
    next();
});
```

});

});

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err) return cb(err);
    cb(null, isMatch);
});
```

};

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

[Developer Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSaRr.png)

Comment: Can you please add your `../model/userModel.js` file?

Comment: Does it throw any error?

Comment: By the way, you should not send back `404` (which means "not found"), but `400` ("bad request")

Comment: No error being throw...

Answer (score 0):

you are using get method method while in express router you are using `app.post`

use method="post" so that you can get from body.property

```
<form action="userSignUp" method="post">
```

Comment: in chrome network request tab click on request url and look in preview for response code, status code or error. there must be something. atlease what you are sending to server and what server sending back

Comment: I did, please find the Developer Tools above. And after a long waiting, the page result in err "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"